# I want to have 2 paths in the program, one is the main page with its sub-pages and the other is the admin panel. How can I do that?in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

this is my index.js code

```
ReactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>

    //panel admin
  <Route path="/admin" element={<PanelAdmin />} />

   //this my home page
    //i try path="/*" but not worked because show notFoundPage i won't that
  <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
</Routes>
```

);

and this my main.js code
i want switch my page in main, and i want my header and footer stay static

```
 <Row>
  <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      <Route path="/personalLife" element={<PersonalLife />} />
      <Route path="/workingLife" element={<WorkingLifePage />} />
    </Routes>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

i'm using react-router-dom v6

and when i go my project in localhost:3000 i have my home page without error's but when i go in localhost:3000/workingLife i have this error's

```
No routes matched location "/workingLife"  
at Routes (webpack://expert/./node_modules/react-router/index.js?:920:5)
at Router (webpack://expert/./node_modules/react-router/index.js?:854:15)
at BrowserRouter (webpack://expert/./node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js?:119:5)
```

and this my link

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Col
    as={NavLink}
    to="/personalLife"
    ref={left}
    id="personalLife"
    className="bg-danger split left "
    xs={6}
    sm={6}
    md={6}
    lg={6}
    xl={6}
  >
    <PersonalLife />
  </Col>
  <Col
    as={NavLink}
    to="/workingLife"
    ref={right}
    id="skillAbility"
    className="bg-warning split right"
    xs={6}
    sm={6}
    md={6}
    lg={6}
    xl={6}
  >
    <WorkingLife />
  </Col>
</React.Fragment>
```

how can fix this !!!!????

Answer (score 0):

You could -if you are holding the data that user is an admin or not- have an if statement to display that route only to the admin users. You should also don't have multiple routers that may cause some issues. Provide all your paths in the first router and have a ternary operator like this

`isAdmin ? <Route path='/admin' element{<PanelAdmin />}/> : null`

This should not allow anyone to access your admin page if they are not an admin